# How to get hg branch name in jenkins file

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, mercurial

I'm working with jenkins file pipeline and i want to show the **hg** branch name in the current build name ( instead of the build number ).
I tried with this code: currentBuild.displayName = "${BRANCH_NAME}" but it returned **null**.
Is there other solution ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is another environment variable for mercurial:
`${MERCURIAL_REVISION_BRANCH}`. This should not be null in case it is a branch being built. The feature got inserted by this [pull request](https://github.com/jenkinsci/mercurial-plugin/pull/62)

Comment: That's exactly what i need. It worked for me. Thank you !

Comment: Then please accept the answer with the check mark.